# iPhone's mail "To" field.. is that a UITextField or a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I am trying to replicate the iPhone mail box in my app. I was wondering if the "To" field they are using in the app is a TextField or a TextView. If yes, they are adding multiple lines for the recipient names.. guidance from any one who has worked on it before would be helpful..

Answer (score 1):

The Mac version is called `NSTokenField`, but there's no public API equivalent for iOS. You can use `TTPickerTextField` from the [Three20 project](https://github.com/facebook/three20/) to get something similar.

Answer (score 0):

it's something different. you can't have the bubble effect with a basic uitextview or uitextfield.

take a look at the Three20 library. They may have something similar